# Finding the inverse of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{49}u^i$ where $u$ is a complex root of $x^{50}-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, inverse, euclidean-algorithm

Consider $p(x)=x^{50}-2\in\Bbb Q[x]$ and $u\in\Bbb C$ such that $p(u)=0\ \ $  ($u^{50}=2$)

By Eisentsein $p(x)$ is irreducible.

If we define $\mu:=1+u+...+u^{49}$ multiplying by $u$ gives $$u+u^2+...+u^{49}+2=u\cdot\mu=\mu+1$$

$\implies \mu(u-1)-1=0$

How should I use the extended euclidean algorithm to find $\mu^{-1}$?

Comment: How do you get from $u\cdot\mu=\mu+1$ to $\mu(1-u)=0$?

Comment: @BarryCipra corrected it

Answer (score 4):

You have the sum of a geometric sequence, so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{49}u^k=\frac{u^{50}-1}{u-1}=\frac{1}{u-1}
$$
because $u^{50}=2$.

The inverse is $u-1$.

Comment: Seems to be correct... But how would you do it using the extended euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @JohnCataldo You conclude $\mu(1-u)=1$, but it should be $\mu(u-1)=1$. What do you mean by “using the extended Euclidean algorithm”? The equality says the inverse of $\mu$ is $u-1$.